# ModuleNotFoundError using setup.py

Tags: python

I use python click package and setuptools to create a simple command line.
And I work in a pipenv virtualenv.

My working directory is like this：

jkt/scripts/app.py

And my setup.py is like this:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(

  name='jkt',
  version='0.1',
  packages=find_packages(),
  include_package_data=True,
  entry_points='''
      [console_scripts]
      jktool=jkt.scripts.app:my_function 
  ''',

)
```

Then I run the command
`pip install --editable .`

And run jktool to execute `my_function` but I get the error:

> ModuleNotFoundError No module named 'jkt'.

But when the `app.py` in jkt directory I can run my function

```
setup(
    name='app',
    version='0.1',
    py_modules=['app'],
    entry_points='''
        [console_scripts]
        app=app:jktools
    ''',
)
```

After I run `pip install -e .` I can use app command to run my function.

Comment: I can't reproduce your error, creating the same directory tree, a trivial `app.py` with `def somefunction(): print("Works")`, and installing with `--user` (to avoid global install). I can get an `ImportError` on Python 2.7 (if I don't put empty `__init__.py` files in `jkt/` and `jkt/scripts/`), but for modern Python 3.7 (where `ModuleNotFoundError` is an `ImportError` subclass and implicit namespace packages are a thing), it works just fine.

Comment: @saluton Please share how you solved this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[As I mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54819576/modulenotfounderror-using-setup-py#comment96414580_54819576), I can't reproduce your error (Python 3.7 with modern `pip` seems to work just fine), but there are a couple things that could potentially be going wrong on older versions.

Since it doesn't look like you put `__init__.py` files in your subdirectories, `find_packages` doesn't actually find any packages at all (`python3 -c 'from setuptools import find_packages; print(find_packages())` prints the empty `list`, `[]`). You can fix this in one of three ways:

1. Create empty `__init__.py` files to explicitly mark those folders as package folders; on a UNIX-like system, `touch jkt/__init__.py` and `touch jkt/scripts/__init__.py` is enough to create them
2. Python 3.3+ only: (also requires modern `setuptools` so `pip install --upgrade setuptools` might be necessary) Replace your use of `find_packages` with [`find_namespace_packages` (which recognizes Python 3 era implicit namespace packages)](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#find-namespace-packages).
3. Just get rid of `find_packages` entirely and list the packages directly, e.g. replace `packages=find_packages(),` with `packages=['jkt', 'jkt.scripts'],`

Options #2 only works on Python 3.3+, so if your package is intended to work on older versions of Python, go with option #1 or #3.

Comment: oh Thanks but it doesn't work I don't know where went wrong. I create a virtualenv 3.7 and have a __init__ file. And when I run pipenv graph it has a packeage named jkt but the program when I run it, it still can not find the module jkt. I will create a simple case to test. I have a question about when I run pip install -e . if it create a package named jkt? and when I run myfunction in shell if it will to load the package first and where the package is.

Comment: I solved this problem.thanks again, maybe I I don't have a clear list of directories and packages.